# Find value of dynamically created element using jquery in nodejs

Tags: jquery, node.js

I have added a few table rows in my html page using jquery's method .after()
However when i am trying to access this element's value in one of my nodejs methods, it returns undefined.
I check the page source and it seems that these newly created elements are not present in the page source even though clearly i can see them.
IS there a different method that i need to use to insert the elements into the body of my page?
Thanks a tonne!

Comment: Isn't node.js server-side and jQuery client-side?

Comment: Yes my nodejs application has a frontend with jade and jquery. Node gets the body elements using request variable in the function called on a route

Comment: Can you show us some code? Especially this part, because I don't understand what you mean: "Node gets the body elements using request variable in the function called on a route".